# Update, Insert, Delete records Joomla Table

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm able to fetch information for whatever table I need the **problem here is the update, insert, and delete records, is not working.**.

I have read the Joomla doc's but even doing the simplest update queries are not working... so here is my code:

UPDATE:

```
// I'm getting the data from an array
 if (!empty($_POST['data'])) {
  $getData = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
 }
// after this line I have a foreach for the array
// in the foreach I have a few IF's
// ether if the result from IF is True or False
// in both I have similar queries
// So let say IF return true;
// Lets prepare the Data using OBJECT's

 $object = new stdClass();
 $object->product_id = $v['product_id'];
 $object->product_name = $v['product_name'];
 $object->product_price = $v['product_price'];
 $object->product_number = $v['product_number'];

 $result = JFactory::getDbo()->updateObject('#__tienda_product', $object, 'product_number');
// that should Update my tables but it doesn't ... now my table has about 21 columns 
// but I only need to update 4 columns base on the column product_number
```

You might have notice the $v['product_id'] where $v is from the foreach, the foreach and the first query are working fine, I did a few echo's before moving to the Update part just to make sure I'm getting the correct data in a format that it should be... any way... the Update part is not working... so I thought it may be because of my table I when to use one table from the regular instalation of joomla... but it still the same no result on the update...

Does any one know how to "update" a table using Joomla CMS as framework?...

Remember I want to use the updateObject() method...

Why don't I use Joomla Framework instead of the CMS's library? 
Well, I can give you a few examples, let say:

a business man want a simple basic report, he doesn't care about managing the site he has people to do that, he also gets a sales report, but he doesn't trust the crew just yet and he want to able to see and compare the result, and he needs and standalone without all the fancy tools that joomla has and for that he need an standalone app that can give that kind of report... ok I might have gone a bit far, but the idea is to have basic, simple, easy to read reports and updates, and that is why I have started this project.

Again, I already went to joomla and read the docs but following their examples it just not working... now, am I have to declear all of the columns even if they don't need to be update? or am I missing an execution for the query which in joomla doesn't mention any executions when using $object() only when using regular queries SQL... the idea is to use $object() ... 

Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the updateobject as a variable, and are not calling it. try changing this:

```
$result = JFactory::getDbo()->updateObject('#__tienda_product', $object, 'product_number');
```

to this:

```
JFactory::getDbo()->updateObject('#__tienda_product', $object, 'product_number');
```

Also, on a side note, you should not use `$_POST` and instead should use [JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)

Comment: that didn't do a thing... and yes I thought of that too, I was using the $result in a $print_r(); ... I just removed it but didn't do anything, the result is the same... Thank you.

Comment: What's your primary key for this table? `product_id` or `product_number`? And have you tried using `var_dump(...);` to see if any results actually exist?

Comment: the primary ID is product_id, but since we are comparing two different sets of data bases, one is local and the other is live, so the local doesn't have the same ID's the only thing that is the same in both are the product_number or SKU if you want to call it that, so when they send the request I don't use the product_id to compare or to find the product in question, what I use is the product_number since that info is the same in both DB's ...

Comment: yes I was using print_r();... anyway, I just got it working, you weren't that far by mentioning the product_id... I have a function that prevent from changing the ID's on the product!! I totally for got about that and because of that it was retuning false for the update, and by misplacing the $print_r() what i was seen was the data that should be updated not the actual result from the update... little thing can give you a huge headache... is working now. Thank you.